# Python: emulate C-style pass-by-reference for variables

Tags: python, c, reference

I have a framework with some C-like language. Now I'm re-writing that framework and the language is being replaced with Python.

**I need to find appropriate Python replacement for the following code construction:**

```
SomeFunction(&arg1)
```

What this does is a C-style pass-by-reference so the variable can be changed inside the function call.

My ideas:

1. just return the value like `v = SomeFunction(arg1)`

   is not so good, because my generic function can have a lot of arguments like `SomeFunction(1,2,'qqq','vvv',.... and many more)`
   and I want to give the user ability to get the value she wants.
2. Return the collection of all the arguments no matter have they changed or not, like: `resulting_list =  SomeFunction(1,2,'qqq','vvv',.... and many more)` `interesting_value = resulting_list[3]`

   this can be improved by giving names to the values and returning dictionary `interesting_value = resulting_list['magic_value1']`

   It's not good because we have constructions like

   ```
   DoALotOfStaff( [SomeFunction1(1,2,3,&arg1,'qq',val2),
                   SomeFunction2(1,&arg2,v1),
                   AnotherFunction(),
                   ...
                  ], flags1, my_var,... )
   ```

   And I wouldn't like to load the user with list of list of variables, with names or indexes she(the user) should know. The kind-of-references would be very useful here ...

**Final Response**

I compiled all the answers with my own ideas and was able to produce the solution. It works.

1. Usage

   ```
   SomeFunction(1,12, get.interesting_value)
   AnotherFunction(1, get.the_val, 'qq')
   ```
2. Explanation

   Anything prepended by `get.` is kind-of reference, and its value will be filled by the function. There is no need in previous defining of the value.

   Limitation - currently I support only numbers and strings, but these are sufficient form my use-case.
3. Implementation

   - wrote a Getter class which overrides **getattribute** and produces any variable on demand
   - all newly created variables has pointer to their container Getter and support method set(self,value)
   - when set() is called it checks if the value is int or string and creates object inheriting from int or str accordingly but with addition of the same set() method. With this new object we replace our instance in the Getter container

Thank you everybody. I will mark as "answer" the response which led me on my way, but all of you helped me somehow.

Comment: In python, all the parameters are passed by reference only. :)

Comment: @thefourtheye What you call "pass by reference" is **not** what C++ people (and lots of other languages - they used the term first!) mean by "pass by reference". That's why there is back draft against saying Python does "pass by reference".

Comment: So, a question for the OP: are you trying to change `arg1` so that the value it refers to is changed by the function, or are you trying to change it so that it actually refers to an entirely different object after the function call?  If it's the latter, this is not exactly supported in Python...in fact it is sort of not in C either, but in C you can always add another level of pointer indirection.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would say that your best, cleanest, bet would be to construct an object containing the values to be passed and/or modified - this single object can be passed, (and will automatically be passed by reference), in as a single parameter and the members can be modified to return the new values.

This will simplify the code enormously and you can cope with optional parameters, defaults, etc., cleanly.

```
>>> class C:
...    def __init__(self):
...        self.a = 1
...        self.b = 2
... 
>>> c=C
>>> def f(o):
...    o.a = 23
... 
>>> f(c)
>>> c
<class __main__.C at 0x7f6952c013f8>
>>> c.a
23
>>>
```

## Note

I am sure that you could extend this idea to have a class of parameter that carried immutable and mutable data into your function with fixed member names plus storing the names of the parameters actually passed then on return map the mutable values back into the caller parameter name.  This technique could then be wrapped into a decorator.

I have to say that it sounds like a lot of work compared to re-factoring your existing code to a more object oriented design.

Comment: This corresponds to my idea N2. It implicates that user knows the names of arguments. It's not that bad, but I'm trying to find even simpler approach. Because in the existing framework the user shouldn't know the names...

Comment: Note that the object is not returned it is modified "in place" and additional members can be added.

Answer (score 2):

This is how Python works already:

```
def func(arg):
  arg += ['bar']

arg = ['foo']
func(arg)
print arg
```

Here, the change to `arg` automatically propagates back to the caller.

For this to work, you have to be careful to *modify* the arguments in place instead of *re-binding* them to new objects. Consider the following:

```
def func(arg):
  arg = arg + ['bar']

arg = ['foo']
func(arg)
print arg
```

Here, `func` rebinds `arg` to refer to a brand new list and the caller's `arg` remains unchanged.

Comment: No, it's not how Python works already. It's strictly weaker than C++'s references. For example, `void zero(T &a) { a = 0; }` works, whereas the equivalent Python function is a no-op.

Comment: @delnan: I was not arguing that the syntax is the same or even similar to C++ (and the question isn't even *about* C++ despite the confused terminology). All I am saying is "pass a mutable object and modify it to your heart's content."

Comment: Well it's interesting but won't work with the primitives like numbers and strings, which are our main use case... I want to get back some primitive values, that's all.

Comment: No, you passed it with reference. The original varaible left unchanged because in Python,  strings are immutable. When you try to modify it, Python creates a new reference to the string.

Answer (score 1):

Python doesn't come with this sort of thing built in. You could make your own class which provides this behavior, but it will only support a slightly more awkward syntax where the caller would construct an instance of that class (equivalent to a pointer in C) before calling your functions. It's probably not worth it. I'd return a "[named tuple](http://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.namedtuple)" (look it up) instead--I'm not sure any of the other ways are really better, and some of them are more complex.

Answer (score 1):

There is a major inconsistency here. The drawbacks you're describing against the proposed solutions are related to such subtle rules of good design, that your question becomes invalid. The whole problem lies in the fact that your function violates the [Single Responsibility Principle](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single_responsibility_principle) and other guidelines related to it (function shouldn't have more than 2-3 arguments, etc.). There is really no smart compromise here:

- either you accept one of the proposed solutions (i.e. [Steve Barnes's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20030209/2642204) concerning your own wrappers or [John Zwinck's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20030386/2642204) concerning usage of named tuples) and refrain from focusing on good design subtleties (as your whole design is bad anyway at the moment)
- or you fix the design. Then your current problem will disappear as you won't have the [God Objects/Functions](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/God_object) (the name of the function in your example - `DoALotOfStuff` really speaks for itself) to deal with anymore.